# Cannot connect to internet in Ubuntu 16.10 Recovery mode

Tags: networking, network-manager

So I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.10 but once I reached the login screen, my mouse and keyboard would not work so I googled for answers and one thing was to boot the machine in recovery mode (Did that) then drop down to a root terminal (Did that too) then run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

but I was unable to connect to the internet, so I exited the root terminal and chose another option which was supposed to enable networking but when I use that, it says

```
grep: /etc/resolv.conf No such file or directory
```

so I assume that's the problem, does anybody know how I can fix this?

P.S. I also understand I could create the file using the root terminal but what would the contents of it be?

I also noticed that although I am unable to move mouse and/or use my keyboard at the login screen, I do see a notification saying I connected to the internet successfully so it seems the internet only doesn't work in recovery mode.

Comment: I think you need to mount the filesystem first then that file will available...

Comment: How would I go about that?